# Can we use a single sample from a population to create confidence intervals, do hypothesis testing, etc.?

Tags: statistics, sampling

When conducting confidence intervals, hypothesis testing, and ANOVAs are we using the sampling distribution with multiple samples as opposed to a single sample?

Are there cases where we use just a single sample, or are we always using the sampling distribution to do the aforementioned tests?

Second question - If we are using a sampling distribution how many samples makes that distribution effective?

Thank you

Comment: Up to now I have constructed only confidence intervals with one single sample and a sample size of n.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the idea of constructing a confidence interval from a point sample, i.e. a sample of size $n=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: One observation is not enough because it give you no idea of the variance (or SD) and you need that for a test or for a CI. (If you already know the variance, then you might make a CI, but it would probably be too long to be of any use; see answer to second question below.)

Second question: This gets into more complicated territory. It's easier to discuss for CIs. For the moment consider we're sampling from a normal population with known SD $\sigma_0$ and unknown mean $\mu.$ Then a 95% CI for $\mu$ is $\bar X \pm 1.96 \sigma_0/\sqrt{n}.$ The length of this CI is $3.92 \sigma_0/\sqrt{n}.$ A hugely long CI isn't of much use. If you're trying to make a small CI, then the bigger $\sigma_0$ the bigger $n$ must be. (You could also make the CI shorter by using a lower confidence level. For example, with the same $\sigma_0$ and $n$, a 90% CI is shorter than a 95% CI.

The same issues arise if $\sigma$ is unknown. Then you'll use the
t distribution to find the CI. The details are a bit more complicated, but the same trade-offs need to be made.

You don't have much control over the variance. So three factors are in tension with one another: (a) confidence level (big is good), (b) sample size (small is good), and (c) length of CI (small is good).
The only way you can improve one of the three is to make one or
both of the other two worse.

The similar problem for testing is a matter of computing the power
of the test. If you know about that, let me know and I'll post an
addendum to this Answer.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I am not talking about the sample size n. I am talking about the idea of a sample of size n vs. multiple sample sizes of n.

Comment: @Raspo: Sorry to be dense, but both the original and your attempt to clarify can have several interpretations. Please give a specific example. By 'multiple' do you mean you have $g$ groups from possibly different populations? By $n$ do you mean the number of replications in each group? By CI, do you mean for the population mean of a single group, or do you mean to get a CI for the difference of two group population means? Specifically, what are the values of $g$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me. When I say I have **g** groups I mean groups from the same population. When I say **n** I mean the number of data points from that sample group **g**. 
Example:
-The population is the height of women aged 21-30 in the United States.
-Our sample size for this study is **n** = 1000.
-We take one sample **g** for the study with sample size **n** = 1000.

My original question was wondering whether it was necessary to have more than one **g** (I think this is called a 'Sampling Distribution') from the same population to do confidence intervals, hypothesis testing etc.?

Comment: Turns out that is the Question I answered. One group is fine, but you get best results (narrowest CIs) when the sample size is large.